# What's wrong with my Pyflink setup that Python UDFs throw py4j exceptions?

Tags: apache-flink, pyflink

I'm playing with the flink python datastream tutorial from the documentation: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/python/datastream_tutorial/

### Environment

My environment is on Windows 10. `java -version` gives:

```
openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9, mixed mode)
```

I tried several ways to set up a python environment for flink. The result is identical.

**Option 1 (with conda)**:

```
conda create -n streaming-experiments python=3.8.10
conda activate streaming-experiments
pip install apache-flink==1.13.1
```

**Option 2 (with system python + poetry)**:

- Installed python 3.8.10 on system level
- pyproject.toml dependencies:

```
pandas = ">=1.0"
httpx = "*"
pyarrow = "*"
apache-flink = "^1.13.1"
```

- Install dependencies:

```
"C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe" -m pip install poetry
poetry install
```

### The problem

Minimal example:

```py
from pyflink.common.serialization import Encoder
from pyflink.common.typeinfo import Types
from pyflink.datastream import StreamExecutionEnvironment
from pyflink.datastream.connectors import StreamingFileSink


def tutorial():
    env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
    env.set_parallelism(1)
    ds = env.from_collection(
        collection=[(1, 'aaa'), (2, 'bbb')],
        type_info=Types.ROW([Types.INT(), Types.STRING()])
    ).map(lambda l: l, output_type=Types.ROW([Types.INT(), Types.STRING()]))
    ds.print()
    ds.add_sink(StreamingFileSink
                .for_row_format('./output', Encoder.simple_string_encoder())
                .build())
    env.execute("tutorial_job")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tutorial()
```

If I run the example from the documentation it works. As soon as I add the "map" operation with a python udf I'm getting py4j errors. This is what I get:

```
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\streaming-experiments\python.exe C:/Users/myuser/PycharmProjects/streaming-experiments/example.py
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner (file:/C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Local/Continuum/miniconda3/envs/streaming-experiments/Lib/site-packages/pyflink/lib/flink-dist_2.11-1.13.1.jar) to field java.lang.String.value
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/myuser/PycharmProjects/streaming-experiments/example.py", line 22, in <module>
    tutorial()
  File "C:/Users/myuser/PycharmProjects/streaming-experiments/example.py", line 18, in tutorial
    env.execute("tutorial_job")
  File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\streaming-experiments\lib\site-packages\pyflink\datastream\stream_execution_environment.py", line 645, in execute
    return JobExecutionResult(self._j_stream_execution_environment.execute(j_stream_graph))
  File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\streaming-experiments\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1285, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\streaming-experiments\lib\site-packages\pyflink\util\exceptions.py", line 146, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\streaming-experiments\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1.execute.
: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:144)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniClusterJobClient.lambda$getJobExecutionResult$3(MiniClusterJobClient.java:137)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:642)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaInvocationHandler.lambda$invokeRpc$0(AkkaInvocationHandler.java:237)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils$1.onComplete(FutureUtils.java:1081)
    at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:264)
    at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:261)
    at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:191)
    at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:188)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.Executors$DirectExecutionContext.execute(Executors.java:73)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:44)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:252)
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef.$bang(AskSupport.scala:572)
    at akka.pattern.PipeToSupport$PipeableFuture$$anonfun$pipeTo$1.applyOrElse(PipeToSupport.scala:22)
    at akka.pattern.PipeToSupport$PipeableFuture$$anonfun$pipeTo$1.applyOrElse(PipeToSupport.scala:21)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$andThen$1.apply(Future.scala:436)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$andThen$1.apply(Future.scala:435)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:90)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:44)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:138)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:82)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:207)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.maybeHandleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:197)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.updateTaskExecutionStateInternal(DefaultScheduler.java:188)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:677)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerNG.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerNG.java:79)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.updateTaskExecutionState(JobMaster.java:435)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:305)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:212)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:77)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:158)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:26)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:170)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
    at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:225)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:592)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:561)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create stage bundle factory! INFO:root:Initializing python harness: C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\streaming-experiments\lib\site-packages\pyflink\fn_execution\beam\beam_boot.py --id=1-1 --provision_endpoint=localhost:56474

    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.runners.python.beam.BeamPythonFunctionRunner.createStageBundleFactory(BeamPythonFunctionRunner.java:429)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.runners.python.beam.BeamPythonFunctionRunner.open(BeamPythonFunctionRunner.java:273)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.AbstractPythonFunctionOperator.open(AbstractPythonFunctionOperator.java:121)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.OneInputPythonFunctionOperator.open(OneInputPythonFunctionOperator.java:108)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.initializeStateAndOpenOperators(OperatorChain.java:437)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreGates(StreamTask.java:582)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$SynchronizedStreamTaskActionExecutor.call(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:100)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.executeRestore(StreamTask.java:562)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runWithCleanUpOnFail(StreamTask.java:647)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restore(StreamTask.java:537)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:759)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:566)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Process died with exit code 0
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2050)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3952)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3974)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4958)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4964)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$SimpleStageBundleFactory.<init>(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:451)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$SimpleStageBundleFactory.<init>(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:436)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory.forStage(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:303)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.runners.python.beam.BeamPythonFunctionRunner.createStageBundleFactory(BeamPythonFunctionRunner.java:427)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Process died with exit code 0
    at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.environment.ProcessManager$RunningProcess.isAliveOrThrow(ProcessManager.java:75)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.environment.ProcessEnvironmentFactory.createEnvironment(ProcessEnvironmentFactory.java:112)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$1.load(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:252)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$1.load(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:231)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3528)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2277)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2154)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2044)
    ... 20 more


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tried to find out if py4j itself works. But it does. This prints me two numbers, so it seems to work:

```py
from py4j.java_gateway import JavaGateway, launch_gateway
launch_gateway(25333, die_on_exit=True)
gateway = JavaGateway()
random = gateway.jvm.java.util.Random()
number1 = random.nextInt(10)
number2 = random.nextInt(10)
print(number1, number2)
```

Any hint what to check or test is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, now after hours of troubleshooting I found out that the issue is not with my python or java setup or with pyflink.

The issue is my company proxy. I didn't think of networking, but py4j needs networking under the hood. Should have spent more attention to this line in the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create stage bundle factory! INFO:root:Initializing python harness: C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\streamexp-yYteoysd-py3.8\lib\site-packages\pyflink\fn_execution\beam\beam_boot.py --id=1-1 --provision_endpoint=localhost:53816
```

The solution is simply to set one environment variable:

`set no_proxy=localhost`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution also by ckecking the network, I modified the /etc/hosts file and I added the following line:

127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4

and after that it will work !