# pyflink with kafka java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create stage bundle factory

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-beam, flink-streaming, py4j, pyflink

・Python3.8
・JDK 11

I've started learning pyflink and write a code instructed by official web which is https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/python/datastream/intro_to_datastream_api/

And here is my code

```
from pyflink.common.serialization import JsonRowDeserializationSchema,JsonRowSerializationSchema
from pyflink.common import WatermarkStrategy, Row
from pyflink.common.serialization import Encoder
from pyflink.common.typeinfo import Types
from pyflink.datastream import StreamExecutionEnvironment
from pyflink.datastream.connectors import FlinkKafkaConsumer,FlinkKafkaProducer

def streaming():
    env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()

    deserialization_schema =JsonRowDeserializationSchema.builder().type_info(
        type_info=Types.ROW([Types.INT(), Types.STRING()])).build()

    kafka_consumer = FlinkKafkaConsumer(
        topics='test',
        deserialization_schema=deserialization_schema,
        properties={'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092','group.id': 'test_group'})

    ds = env.add_source(kafka_consumer)
    ds = ds.map(lambda a: Row(a % 4, 1),
                output_type=Types.ROW([Types.LONG(), Types.LONG()])) \
        .key_by(lambda a: a[0]) \
        .reduce(lambda a, b: Row(a[0], a[1] + b[1]))

    serialization_schema = JsonRowSerializationSchema.builder().with_type_info(
        type_info=Types.ROW([Types.LONG(), Types.LONG()])).build()


    kafka_sink = FlinkKafkaProducer(
        topic='test_sink_topic',
        serialization_schema=serialization_schema,
        producer_config={'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092',
                         'group.id': 'test_group'})
    ds.add_sink(kafka_sink)

    env.execute('datastream_api_demo')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    streaming()
```

Firstly it said to me to specify jarfile. So I downloaded flink-connector-kafka and kafka-clients jarfile for each from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink and put them into pyflink/lib directory.

And now I'm at next step getting this error;

```
(pyflink_demo) C:\work\pyflink_demo>python Kafka_stream_Kafka.py
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner (file:/C:/work/pyflink_demo/Lib/site-packages/pyflink/lib/flink-dist_2.11-1.14.4.jar) to field java.util.P
roperties.serialVersionUID
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Kafka_stream_Kafka.py", line 38, in <module>
    streaming()
  File "Kafka_stream_Kafka.py", line 33, in streaming
    env.execute('datastream_api_demo')
  File "C:\work\pyflink_demo\lib\site-packages\pyflink\datastream\stream_execution_environment.py", line 691, in execute
    return JobExecutionResult(self._j_stream_execution_environment.execute(j_stream_graph))
  File "C:\work\pyflink_demo\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1285, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "C:\work\pyflink_demo\lib\site-packages\pyflink\util\exceptions.py", line 146, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\work\pyflink_demo\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o0.execute.
: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:144)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniClusterJobClient.lambda$getJobExecutionResult$3(MiniClusterJobClient.java:137)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:642)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaInvocationHandler.lambda$invokeRpc$1(AkkaInvocationHandler.java:258)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
        at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.doForward(FutureUtils.java:1389)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.lambda$null$1(ClassLoadingUtils.java:93)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:68)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.lambda$guardCompletionWithContextClassLoader$2(ClassLoadingUtils.java:92)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.AkkaFutureUtils$1.onComplete(AkkaFutureUtils.java:47)
        at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:300)
        at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:297)
        at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:224)
        at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:221)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.AkkaFutureUtils$DirectExecutionContext.execute(AkkaFutureUtils.java:65)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:68)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1(Promise.scala:284)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1$adapted(Promise.scala:284)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:284)
        at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef.$bang(AskSupport.scala:621)
        at akka.pattern.PipeToSupport$PipeableFuture$$anonfun$pipeTo$1.applyOrElse(PipeToSupport.scala:24)
        at akka.pattern.PipeToSupport$PipeableFuture$$anonfun$pipeTo$1.applyOrElse(PipeToSupport.scala:23)
        at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$andThen$1(Future.scala:532)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:29)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:29)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:63)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:100)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
        at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:81)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:100)
        at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:49)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:48)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:138)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:82)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:252)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.maybeHandleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:242)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.updateTaskExecutionStateInternal(DefaultScheduler.java:233)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:684)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerNG.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerNG.java:79)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.updateTaskExecutionState(JobMaster.java:444)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.lambda$handleRpcInvocation$1(AkkaRpcActor.java:316)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:83)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:314)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:217)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:78)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:163)
        at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:24)
        at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:20)
        at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
        at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:122)
        at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:20)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
        at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:537)
        at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:535)
        at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:220)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:580)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:548)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:270)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:231)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:243)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create stage bundle factory! INFO:root:Initializing Python harness: C:\work\pyflink_demo\lib\site-packages\pyflink\fn_execution\beam\bea
m_boot.py --id=4-1 --provision_endpoint=localhost:51794
INFO:root:Starting up Python harness in loopback mode.

        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.runners.python.beam.BeamPythonFunctionRunner.createStageBundleFactory(BeamPythonFunctionRunner.java:566)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.runners.python.beam.BeamPythonFunctionRunner.open(BeamPythonFunctionRunner.java:255)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.AbstractPythonFunctionOperator.open(AbstractPythonFunctionOperator.java:131)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.AbstractOneInputPythonFunctionOperator.open(AbstractOneInputPythonFunctionOperator.java:116)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.PythonProcessOperator.open(PythonProcessOperator.java:59)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.RegularOperatorChain.initializeStateAndOpenOperators(RegularOperatorChain.java:110)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreGates(StreamTask.java:711)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$SynchronizedStreamTaskActionExecutor.call(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:100)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreInternal(StreamTask.java:687)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restore(StreamTask.java:654)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:958)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:927)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:766)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:575)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Process died with exit code 0
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2050)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3952)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3974)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4958)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4964)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$SimpleStageBundleFactory.<init>(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:451)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$SimpleStageBundleFactory.<init>(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:436)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory.forStage(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:303)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.runners.python.beam.BeamPythonFunctionRunner.createStageBundleFactory(BeamPythonFunctionRunner.java:564)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Process died with exit code 0
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.environment.ProcessManager$RunningProcess.isAliveOrThrow(ProcessManager.java:75)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.environment.ProcessEnvironmentFactory.createEnvironment(ProcessEnvironmentFactory.java:112)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$1.load(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:252)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$1.load(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:231)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3528)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2277)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2154)
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2044)
        ... 22 more
```

I tried to figure out what's going on and found very similar question [What's wrong with my Pyflink setup that Python UDFs throw py4j exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68015759/whats-wrong-with-my-pyflink-setup-that-python-udfs-throw-py4j-exceptions/68040220#68040220)
It says that was caused by network proxy problem. JVM and python uses local socket communication. So set local communication with no proxy.

I set environment valuable "no_proxy" but it doesn't work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9IAu.png)

Could anyone provide solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no useful information in the exception stack to help to identify the problem. This should be caused by a known issue([FLINK-26543](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-26543), already solved, however still not released). This issue only occurs in `loopback` mode which is enabled by default when executing the job locally.

For now, you could try to force the job run in `process` mode instead of `loopback` mode by setting environment variable `_python_worker_execution_mode` to `process`. After doing this, you should see the root cause of the failure.

Besides, there is also a small issue in your code. I guess you meant `ds.map(lambda a: Row(a[0] % 4, 1), output_type=Types.ROW([Types.LONG(), Types.LONG()]))` instead of `ds.map(lambda a: Row(a % 4, 1), output_type=Types.ROW([Types.LONG(), Types.LONG()]))` as it doesn't support `%` operation in `Row` object.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the script. I am not quite sure what caused the error. Try to start kafka first and create the topics, before running the script. Or start kafka and run the script a second time after first failure.