# Custom SourceFunction and SinkFunction in PyFlink

Tags: apache-flink, pyflink

I am new to flink and looking for CustomSource in python to invoke webapi for every 1 minute.

Below is one of the sample that I tried but it didn't work for me.

I understand we should implement SourceFunction and override the run and cancel methods.

class DataGenerator(SourceFunction):
def **init**(self):
super().**init**(self)
self._num_iters = 1000
self._running = True

```
def run(self, ctx):
    counter = 0
    while self._running and counter < self._num_iters:
        ctx.collect('Hello World')
        counter += 1

def cancel(self):
    self._running = False
```

Not sure if Python supports custom source implementation.

I found couple of example using JAVA but not with python.

If someone can provide me an example implementing the custom source that would be great.

I am looking for an example implementing Custom Source function using python and flink.

I have gone through couple of samples and the example provided below.

[Using SourceFunction and SinkFunction in PyFlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74444120/using-sourcefunction-and-sinkfunction-in-pyflink)